# MYSQL View Query Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, mysql5

I have 5 SQL tables

- store
- staff
- departments
- sold_items
- staff_rating

I created a view that JOINs this four of the tables together. The last table (staff_rating),I want to get the rating column at a time close to when items was sold (sold_items.date) for the view rows.
I have tried the following SQL Queries which works but have performance issues.

SQL QUERY 1

```
SELECT s.name,
       s.country,
       d.name,
       si.item, 
       si.date, 
       (SELECT rating 
        FROM staff_ratings 
        WHERE staff_id = s.id 
        ORDER BY DATEDIFF(date, si.date) LIMIT 1) AS rating, 
       st.name, 
       st.owner
   FROM store st
   LEFT OUTER JOIN staff s ON s.store_id = st.id
   LFET JOIN departments d ON d.store_id = st.id
   LEFT JOIN sold_items si ON si.store_id = st.id
```

SQL QUERY 2

```
SELECT s.name,
       s.country,
       d.name,
       si.item, 
       si.date, 
       si.rating , 
       st.name, 
       st.owner
FROM store st
LEFT OUTER JOIN staff s ON s.store_id = st.id
LFET JOIN departments d ON d.store_id = st.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *,
                  (SELECT rating 
                   FROM staff_ratings 
                   WHERE staff_id = si.staff_id 
                   ORDER BY DATEDIFF(date, si.date) LIMIT 1) AS rating 
           FROM sold_items) si ON si.store_id = st.id
```

SQL Query 2 is faster than SQL Query 1. But Both still have performance issue. Appreciate help for a query with better performance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2nd query looks like it is synthactically wrong. It must produce "unknown column" error.

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8+?  Also, what indexes, etc, exist on your tables?  It's also always worth running `EXPLAIN` on your queries if you want us to have any understanding of the behaviour of your existing queries.  Finally, as mentioned, your queries don't appear syntactically correct; please ensure you include the EXACT working queries used - asking us to try to interpret through your typos just makes everything needlessly harder.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question. We need a bit more information to help you.

Comment: @MatBailie, it is MYSQL 5.x

Comment: It looks 'odd' that you join a store to its staff members, then when you join on the sold items, you don't include the staff_id (such that if a store sold 100 items and has 8 staff, you end up with 800 combinations, each of which you then go an look up a staff rating for...)  Is that really correct?  Please edit your question to include the full table definitions, so that we can see which foreign keys actually exist.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't look right to me (as mentioned in a comment on the original post; lacking staff_id in the join on the sales, etc)

Ignoring that, one of your biggest performance hits is likely to be this...

```
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(date, si.date) LIMIT 1
```

That order by can only be answered by comparing EVERY record for that staff member to the current sales record.

What you ideally want to be able to do is find the appropriate staff rating from an index, and not to have to run computations that involve dates from both the ratings table and the sales table.

If, for example, you wanted "the most recent rating BEFORE the sale", the query can be substantially improved...

```
SELECT
   s.name,
   s.country,
   d.name,
   si.item, 
   si.date, 
   (
     SELECT sr.rating 
       FROM staff_ratings sr
      WHERE sr.staff_id = s.id
        AND sr.date <= si.date
   ORDER BY sr.date DESC
      LIMIT 1
   )
    AS rating, 
   st.name, 
   st.owner
FROM store st
LEFT JOIN staff s ON s.store_id = st.id
LFET JOIN departments d ON d.store_id = st.id
LEFT JOIN sold_items si ON si.store_id = st.id
```

Then, with an index for `staff_ratings(staff_id, date, rating)` the optimiser can very quickly look up which rating to use, without having to scan Every Single Rating for that staff member.

Answer (score 0):

Why `DATEDIFF`?  Would something like this work better?  If so, the given index will make it work much faster.

```
WHERE staff_id = s.id
  AND s.date >= s1.date
ORDER BY s.date
LIMIT 1
```

And `INDEX(staff_id, date)`

Do you need `LEFT JOIN`?  Perhaps plain `JOIN`?

`d` may benefit from `INDEX(store_id, name)`